# Help explain how this ac switch circuit works

Tags: power-supply, switches, circuit-analysis, analog

[image: ac switch circuit]

Below is an ac switch circuit. COIL1_EN is used to enable or disable the switch. Does any one know how this ac switch work? I think it may be a standard design, can anyone give the related documents?

Comment: Where did WCT1003A come from? It's not on the schematic.

Comment: I don't think this switch works at all, at least not in this application. It relies on the ability of the control circuit to inject DC current into the circuit being switched, and the schematic on the right does not provide a return path for that current. Note also that VBAT has to be higher than any voltage being switched.

Comment: VBat must be a higher voltage than the circuit being controlled(?). Coil1_EN controls the switch, if there is voltage on VBat. I think.

Comment: This is part of the application circuit of WCT1003A, the COIL1_EN is from WCT1003A。

Comment: VBat is a higher voltage than the circuit being controlled.

Comment: @ChunyuWu: You still haven't told us what a WCT1003A is. Do you expect that we are all familiar with it? Please explain **in your original question** what it is and provide a link to the datasheet.

Comment: This is part of a wireless charger system.  The switch circuit (or multiple switch circuits) performs an analog switching of one or more of the resonant coils.  See spec sheet sections 4 and 4.7,... :  http://cache.nxp.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/user_guide/WCT100XAWCAUG.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The source terminals of the two MOSFETs take on no higher than one body diode drop above the two drains when they are off.

When Q11 is off, R84 keeps the MOSFETs off.

When Q11 is on, the gates rises to near Vbat. Initially, when Vbat is greater than (one diode drop) + (Vce of Q11) + (Vgs-on of Q12) + (one body diode drop) + (the lower of the two drains), the two MOSFET would turn on. Since an MOSFET when on can conduct either way, they let current passes either way. The on-MOSFETs would try to pull the two sources and two drains to the same voltage. There is a possibility that the drain with the higher voltage can pull the sources higher to partially turn the MOSFETs back off. So for the switch to stay on consistently, Vbat has to be a certain level higher than the voltage levels which the MOSFETs switch.